# Multiple integration with stochastic integral

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-integrals, multiple-integral

I am trying to solve following multiple integral where the inner integral is stochastic.

$$ \int_0^t \int_0^s e^{- a (s-u)} \,dW(u) \,ds$$

where a is  a constant and $W$ is a Brownian motion. I can find the distrubtion of the inner integral by using Ito Isometry

$$ \int_0^s e^{-a(s-u)} \,dW(u)  \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{1}{2a} [ 1 - e^{-2 a s} ]\right) $$

So my question is how do I solve an integral of a distribution, which in this example is 
$$ \int_0^t \mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{1}{2a} [ 1 - e^{-2 a s} ] \right) \, ds$$

Thank you for all the responses!

Comment: "So my question is how do I solve an integral of a distribution" You don't, rather you note that $$\int_0^t \int_0^s e^{- a (s-u)} dW(u) ds=\int_0^t \left(\int_u^t e^{- a (s-u)} ds\right) dW(u) =\ldots$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The relation is still a bit hard for me to understand why it is true. Is there a theorem/proof of this relation that can help me to understand why this holds?

Comment: I am afraid you will have to be much more specific here. What is it that you fail to understand in my comment?

Comment: I fail to understand how you can change the order of integration? Can it be shown in more steps?